# How can we use the MLE to test if the population variance is greater than some constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

If we have a density distribution function and we are given four values of $x$, how can we use the MLE to do the Hypothesis testing that variance is greater than some constant?

Comment: If your likelihood has the monotone likelihood ratio property, then you can try to construct a UMP test, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio#Most_powerful_tests:_The_Karlin.E2.80.93Rubin_theorem But this is not related to MLE and it may not be easy to simplify. In large sample theory, Wald test is somehow related to MLE, and it is more flexible and practical. But it require large sample to perform the approximation, so may not be suitable in your case. There are other method to construct tests as well.

Comment: @BGM, Suppose, it doesn't matter if the sample size is large or not and we still use the Wald test for the testing, how can we find the values of $\theta _{MLE}$ and $\theta _0$?

Comment: Emm $\theta_0$ should be the parameter value in your simple null hypothesis, i.e. the "some constant" in your question. The other one is simply the MLE, and I am not sure why you ask how to find MLE which is a routine task.

Comment: @BGM I mean, I found the $\theta_{MLE}$ using the distribution and substituted the values of of the four given points. However, I don't understand what is the $\theta_0$ here and how will it be calculated

Comment: You are testing $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$. The $\theta_0$, i.e. "some constant", is specified in prior, but not calculated.

Comment: @BGM I am testing whether the population variance is greater than some constant i.e. $H_0 : \sigma^2 = c$ vs $H_1 : \sigma^2 \gt c$ where c is some constant. How can I proceed in this case?

Comment: You do not know how to perform Wald test or not sure what is $\theta_0$? As explained above, $\theta_0$ is the "some constant" you stated. If you want to call it as $c$, then $\theta_0$ is your $c$.